# Web app lag on android

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-applications, backbone.js

I'm developing a web app with HTML5, css3 and backbone.js and expected lag issues on android mobiles, however my guess is the css causes all the lags, the app would run smoothly without any css. My question is: Is there anyway that can effectivly reduce lag on android by reducing css or other ways?

Answer (score 1):

yes! You can uglify and minify CSS and slightly reduce the size of the file.

But more importantly, how many different CSS and JS files are you calling in your HTML file? Each CSS is a separate HTTP request and definitely slows down the page loading time. Generally you take the number of milliseconds that it takes to load on a desktop and multiply that by 10 for a fast mobile device. Look at the network tab of the Inspector in Chrome (there are similar features in Firefox and safari) and see what the added load of those extra css files are.

How do you reduce the number? By using SASS. Sass is a preprocessor framework for CSS that condenses all your CSS down to one file elegantly. I recommend using an app called Prepros to handle SASS rendering, more information is available on the Prepros and SASS officialy websites.

How many images are you loading? Using services like Tiny Png can reduce the size of the images without losing any visible quality, mobile devices have less ram and are forced to do compression on the front-end.

You can also use the minified backbone.js file, and minify any js you have yourself. this can be done again with Prepros (and the paid mac app Codekit) or you can use any number of online services.

Basically: You need to compress the size of the files you are using, reduce the number of requests for files, and finally keep working to optimize your own javascript to make it as fast as possible. The next step after that is to start simplifying your app and getting rid of features that aren't needed and focus on the core parts that make it useful and elegant.

Comment: Ty for the reply, I agree the ways to optimize the app and they are useful. But there is still a problem I don't know if it is related to the solution you stated. The web app self is a single page, so all the files(html, css, javascript) loaded in the beginning, after it's done and try to scroll the page is when the lag starts on android.

Comment: Ok, that's why it's important to post exactly what your problem is so the community can answer it better. I will have to see a link to your page so I can see how your code is affecting performance.